# DefaultSubscriptionRegistry and its protected methods

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I am trying to implement a WebSocket feature with STOMP in my SpringBoot application. So far, this is going quite alright, but I'm running into one issue.

Unsubscribing from a topic seems to always be done from the browser's side. However, using @DestinationVariable I can create a number of topics (e.g. with the path /{game_id}/chat), and I need a security feature on the server's side.

Because messages are authorized, I am able to check whether the logged user actually has access to {game_id}. If they don't, the subscription should end (not the WebSocket connection!). To do this, I autowired DefaultSubscriptionRegistry to delete the subscription from the list, but this method is apparently protected. I now find myself not knowing how to delete this subscription (which is managed by the simple broker Spring provides) from inside of Spring.

I guess another way to do this is by mocking an unsubscribe message from the browser and having the MessageHandler handle it. But that gives its own challenges, mainly obtaining the ApplicationContext of the simple broker (that I did not personally edit).

Has anyone faced this challenge before? Are there good workarounds/alternatives to unsubscribe from the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Rossen has given [an answer on GitHub](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/issues/36#issuecomment-41272842) that I believe will help with this.

Essentially, the approach is to [register a `ChannelInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based) that creates a mock unsubscribe message:

```java
@Override
public Message<?> beforeHandle(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, MessageHandler handler) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headers = 
        StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.UNSUBSCRIBE);
    // ... add headers
    Message<?> unsubscribe = MessageBuilder
       .withPayload(new byte[0]).setHeaders(headers).build();
    messageHandler.handleMessage(unsubscribe);
    return message;
}
```

Comment: So the message mocking is indeed the right approach. I must say that I'm quite new to interceptors, but beforeHandle() doesn't exist as a method in ChannelInterceptor. Should I look at a different method for this, or am I instead looking at a different interceptor? Seems to be the ExecutorChannelInterceptor, since preSend and preReceive don't take MessageHandler as input and taking that handler from the ApplicationContext appears to not be very straightforward.

Comment: I'm still trying everything but there just doesn't seem to be a proper way to retrieve the destination in this interceptor, which is required to obtain the game_id and perform the check.

Comment: This is just a guess, but have you already tried inspecting the message headers for the `DESTINATION` header? I believe that's part of the STOMP protocol.

Comment: I have indeed, but all the classes to access these headers do not support a DESTINATION header. We've now settled on not having this extra protection because after many hours of trying different HeaderAccessors we decided it's probably not possible or not meant to be used that way.